# Reverse leakage loss in diode

Tags: power, current, diodes, loss, reverse-bias

How can I calculate the reverse leakage loss in both  diodes (2 switch half bridge rectifier ) ?

I found this equation: \$P_{leak} = (1 + \delta) · I_{rr} · V_{rr}\$.

There is no demonstration.

Is it true?

Comment: I think the reverse leak current times reverse voltage is clearly reverse leak power. what the problem? please give source of your formular.

Comment: I think that you  cannot open the paper because  it is in the IEE

Comment: Assuming you mean "IEEE" (IEE was a display manufacturer), many people have access to papers. It is better to quote the source **and** copy enough context to make the snippet clear, but not too much that it is not "fair use".

Comment: @Spehro IEE was also the Institute of Electrical Engineers, founded in the UK in the 1880s. Now incorporated into the IET (Institute of Engineering and Technology, I think)

Comment: this is the paper (http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6317196)

Comment: Next time when you ask something you should provide information, source or at least circuit schematic. no one can know which paper you reading.  also don't talk like toxic people.

Answer (score 1):

The paper in question (https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6317196) is describing a non-synchronous full-wave boost rectifier.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDDb7V.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The losses in any devices is ***ALWAYS*** the voltage across the device multiplied by the current through the device. Now the instantaneous voltage and current may involve some convoluted equation to determine their values but once V and I are determined the loss is V*I

\$1 W = 1 \frac{J}{s} = 1 \frac{Nm}{s} = 1 \frac{kgm^2}{s^3}\$

\$1W = 1V \cdot 1A \$

\$1W = 1 \frac{V^2}{\Omega} = 1 A^2 \cdot \Omega\$

To refute this is to refute the SI unit system.

The forward powerloss is therefore  Vd * Id (where Vd is the forward volt drop and Id is the forward current).

The reverse powerloss (due to leakage) is therefore Vrr * Irr (where Vrr is the reverse blocking voltage and Irr is the reverse flowing current).

Equation 9 in the paper states:

\$P_{leak} = ( 1 + \delta )\cdot I_{rr} \cdot V_{rr} \$

which on the face of this is bringing into question the SI definition of power and what I previously wrote. What is this delta?

If the accompanying paragraph of the paper is taken into consideration:

> Finally, the reverse leakage loss in both diodes combined
> is...

This equation is therefore valid for this topology where there are two source of reverse leakage power loss. Unfortunately the paper fails to define what delta is.

Comment: δ is the "duty ratio" = Ton/(Ton+Toff), as described in reference 17 in the original IEEE paper (another IEEE paper with some authors in common).

Answer (score -2):

It is not correct. The reverse leakage current in diodes depends on the reverse voltage but you cannot simply write this.

A more correct formula will be if you have a resistor connected in series with a reverse biased diode the "reverse leakage" power will be (leakage current)^2 x resistance of the resistor.

Comment: The power dissipated in the diode will *always* be \$V_d · I_d\$.

Comment: No it's not. The 'resistance' of the diode is not ohmic so no power is dissipated on the diode.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether an element is ohmic or not, power dissipation is *always* \$V·I\$ for *everything*. That comes directly out of conservation of energy.

Comment: I think you confuse power dissipation with voltage drop. In non ohmic resistances there is voltage drop but 0 Joule heating->0 power dissipation. And by power dissipation we usually refer to heat.

Comment: Which is what probably the OP is asking.

Comment: No, I'm quite certain you're the one who's confused here. No joule heating doesn't mean no heating (and besides there is *also* joule heating in a non-ideal diode). Why do you think high-power transistors (definitely non-ohmic devices!) so frequently need to be mounted to heatsinks?

Comment: Hearth OK 1 example capacitors in AC don't dissipate power however they provide resistance. The depletion region of the diode is just like a capacitor!

Comment: Ideal capacitors dissipate no power, that is true. They do, however, store and release energy. A reverse-biased diode is like a capacitor, that is also true. But a real capacitor does dissipate power (δ of the dielectric, and also any DC leakage current through the dielectric) and likewise so does a real reverse-biased diode. The fact that it's a capacitor doesn't mean it won't dissipate power. Steady-state DC leakage current will always dissipate power, whether in a transistor or a diode or a capacitor.

Comment: You do, however, have a point that my initial comment was wrong. The power *dissipated or stored* in a diode is \$V_d · I_d\$, but the dissipated power dominates outside of very high frequency transients.

Comment: Hearth you mean the collisions inside the depletion region between free electrons and the lattice. Well OP never specified that kind of detail lol.

Comment: "That kind of detail" is *exactly* what the question is asking about; that and recombination are what reverse leakage losses *are* (and forward conduction losses too!).

Comment: @Force, the AC power (\$\tilde{v}\tilde{i}\$)of an ideal capacitor will be purely imaginary (indicating reactive power and no dissipation). The instantaneous power (\$v(t)i(t)\$) will be positive for half the cycle and negative for half the cycle, with no net power consumption (even if the capacitor is nonlinear).

Comment: The Photon imaginary heat doesn't exist at all.

Comment: @TheForceAwakens You're really misunderstanding a lot here and I'm not sure how to help. You may want to brush up on Laplace-domain stuff.